# esModuleInterop flag set, still getting default import error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have a React project using TypeScript, and in the main tsx file, the `import React from 'react'` line works fine. However in my test file, it's still triggering the TS1259 error. I'm guessing there is something funky with my TS/Jest/Babel config, but can't seem to pin it down.

Anybody know what the issue is?

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "target": "ES2019",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "allowJs": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "strict": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "types": []
    },
    "include": [
        "index.d.ts",
        "src/*.ts",
        "src/*.tsx",
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.tsx"
    ]
}
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{ts,tsx}', '!src/index.ts'],
    moduleNameMapper: {'^.+\\.s?css$': 'identity-obj-proxy'},
    transform: {'^.+\\.tsx?$': 'babel-jest'},
    testRegex: '/__tests__/.*\\.test\\.tsx?$',
    testURL: 'http://localhost',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/__tests__/setup.ts'],
    setupFiles: [],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
        '__snapshots__',
        '__mocks__',
        '<rootDir>/scripts',
    ],
};
```

Error message in Jest test file

[image: Error message in Jest test file]

No error in main component file

[image: No error in main component file]

Comment: That would happen if your test is excluded by the `tsconfig.json` but it doesn't appear to be. It is probably your IDE misunderstanding something. Run `./node_modules/.bin/tsc --noEmit` from the command line to do a typecheck.

Comment: Actually, our tests aren't in the `src` folder, so your suggestion turned out to be 100% correct. Would you mind posting it as an answer so I can mark it as the solution? I knew it was going to be some mundane detail (isn't i always?). Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TypeScript determines which files are considered part of your project based on
a variety of options specified in your `tsconfig.json`.

If you use the `"include"` and/or `"files"` properties to explicitly indicate these files, only those files which match the paths and patterns specified therein, together with those they reference either directly or transitively, are part of the project.

Thus, any settings specified under `"compilerOptions"`, such as `"esModuleInterop"` for example, apply only to these files because only those files are part of the project.

As you have specified

```
"include": [
  "index.d.ts",
  "src/*.ts",
  "src/*.tsx",
  "src/**/*.ts",
  "src/**/*.tsx"
]
```

If your tests are not under the `src` directory, they will not be considered part of your project and your compiler options will not be applied to them.

You can verify which files are included in your project on the command line by running

```
$ tsc --listFilesOnly
```

If you have multiple `tsconfig` files, which is often the case especially in newer projects, you can specify the project as well with the `--project` option

For example

```
$ tsc --listFilesOnly --project ./tsconfig.app.json
```

See the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html#compiler-options) for further details.